# Modifying an existing job in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2005 Express to connect to one of my servers. How do I check the existing jobs in the server I am connected to and modify them?

I am logged in as admin and still can't see the required. I can see the jobs in SQL Server 2000 but not in 2005.

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Ended up downloading the latest version 2008 and which supports Server Agent.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can be helpful for you 
http://sql-articles.com/blogs/script-to-find-sql-job-activity-details/